# How do I manually set cookie in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, session-cookies

I have a situation where I need to send session id in custom header because safari does not allow sending cookie from iframe.

But now, I'm having trouble setting the cookie from rack middleware.

```
status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
session_id = headers['X-SESSION-ID'] || headers['HTTP_X_SESSION_ID'] || headers['x-session-id'] || ''

if !headers['Cookie'].present? && session_id.present?
  headers['Cookie'] = {
    '_session_id': {
      value: session_id,
      path: '/',
      httpOnly: true
    }
  }
end
```

Or is there way to manually set session id without having to fetch it from cookie?

Update 1:

Modifying rack request files does work. But, I'm not sure how to proceed with this one. If nothing works then, I might manually update this file in all servers.

```
def cookies
  hash   = @env["rack.request.cookie_hash"] ||= {}
  string = @env["HTTP_COOKIE"] || "_session_id=#{@env["HTTP_X_SESSION_ID"]}"

  return hash if string == @env["rack.request.cookie_string"]
  hash.clear

  # According to RFC 2109:
  #   If multiple cookies satisfy the criteria above, they are ordered in
  #   the Cookie header such that those with more specific Path attributes
  #   precede those with less specific.  Ordering with respect to other
  #   attributes (e.g., Domain) is unspecified.
  cookies = Utils.parse_query(string, ';,') { |s| Rack::Utils.unescape(s) rescue s }
  cookies.each { |k,v| hash[k] = Array === v ? v.first : v }
  @env["rack.request.cookie_string"] = string
  hash
end
```

Looks like modifying the cookie method as above do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve it. So, I added `rack_request.rb` in `initializers`. And here's the code for it:

```
require 'rack'
require 'rack/request'
require 'rack/utils'

Rack::Request.class_eval do
 def cookies
    hash = @env["rack.request.cookie_hash"] ||= {}
    string = @env["HTTP_COOKIE"] || "_session_id=#{@env['HTTP_X_SESSION_ID']}"

unless string =~ /\s*_session_id=/i
  if  @env['HTTP_X_SESSION_ID'].present?
    string << "; _session_id=#{@env['HTTP_X_SESSION_ID']}"
  end
end

# require 'colorize'
#
# Rails.logger.info 'from cookies'.green
# Rails.logger.info (string.blue)

return hash if string == @env["rack.request.cookie_string"]
hash.clear


# According to RFC 2109:
#   If multiple cookies satisfy the criteria above, they are ordered in
#   the Cookie header such that those with more specific Path attributes
#   precede those with less specific.  Ordering with respect to other
#   attributes (e.g., Domain) is unspecified.
cookies = Rack::Utils.parse_query(string, ';,') { |s| Rack::Utils.unescape(s) rescue s }
cookies.each { |k, v| hash[k] = Array === v ? v.first : v }
@env["rack.request.cookie_string"] = string
hash


 end
end
```

And I'm sending `'X-SESSION-ID'` in my ajaxHeaders for session id.